# Handling Close button of IE Browser

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Script On Close of window in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598070/java-script-on-close-of-window-in-ie8)

I want to close session, when the close button of browser is clicked.

I have handled it using `OnBeforeUnload` in body tag of master page but it is getting fired for even if the end user navigates to other page. So my requirement is call closing session code, only if, the close button of the browser is clicked.

Comment: [tag:java]!=[tag:javascript]

Comment: There are many way to close a program, this will not be bullet proof (i.e. user can kill the browser)

Comment: I need just call my JavaScript function before closing browser..

Comment: @ mplungjan, Is it working in all browser..??

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any way to detect this. Its a common problem that most web developers come across at some point.

The usual way to handle this is to have sessions expire after a period of inactivity (timeout). Many people fall into the trap of thinking there must be a 'better way', but given the nature of the HTTP its actually a very good, elegant solution.